# What is the best way to find which domains in a list of InterPro IDs are catalytic?

Tags: bioinformatics, proteins, enzymes

What is the best way to find which domains in a list of InterPro IDs are catalytic?

(In this case, we are looking at human enzymes and their domains' InterPro IDs.)

Thanks in advance!
Setz

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please finish reading the [tour] to find out how this and other SE sites work. Your question may have a better response on our sister site, SE Bioinformatics, but in any case you should give an indication of the steps you have taken yourself to answer any question you posed here. Personally I would have submitted a [ticket](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/support/interpro) from the Interpro Help page. Some of these large web facilities have very good support (others less so).

Answer (score 0):

In InterPro you can do a search "by text" and type in "catalytic". It gives you a list of IDs with description and you can download the list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!